# Adding MKAnnotation to MKMapView above location, not in center

Tags: swift, swiftui, mkmapview

I have this code in MapView Coordinator class for adding annotation to map:

```
    func mapView(_ mapview: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
         return mapview.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "myiconid")
    }
```

Annotation added in center of my location :

[image]

How can I add annotation above my location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says:

> By default, the center point of an annotation view is placed at the coordinate point of the associated annotation. You can use this property to reposition the annotation view as needed. This x and y offset values are measured in points. Positive offset values move the annotation view down and to the right, while negative values move it up and to the left.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/1452144-centeroffset

So you might want to change the `centerOffset` attribute for your annotations...

Answer (score 0):

Annotation are set on the latitude and longitude that you provide while making it. I think there is no means we can place our annotation above our location unless we change our latitude and longitude.

Comment: Ok, but changing location may be different for different zoom level, not fixed

Comment: If you add the annotation on a particular longitude and latitude that either you zoom in or out. The annotation will be fixed it will not move.

Comment: I have a problem with map rotation also

Comment: You can set map rotation property to **false** to make map no to rotate.

Comment: Can I change rotation of my annotation synchronously with map?

Comment: Annotation will appear according to **device orientation** not according to the rotation of map.